# How should I upload videos to Amazon S3?

Tags: php, javascript, amazon-s3, restful

I have a project which is basically a website like YouTube. I am hosting my videos with Amazon S3.

I am confused as to whether I should upload videos (200mb+) by a PHP script or by browser-based upload. What I mean by browser-based is uploading the videos directly to Amazon S3 using JavaScript and REST.

Which is a better way of uploading videos to Amazon S3?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using youtube as the video hoster, as they have a good system inplace.

That being said, have you had a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683263/html5-resumable-and-chunked-upload-of-large-files-500mb)